# Maven2 plugin dependency

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

I have a troubles with plugin dependecies.

I want to use "proguard-maven-plugin", but by default this plugin use proguard 4.3. Proguard 4.3 don't support jdk 7.

To fix my problem i'm just need to use proguard 4.6+. Buuut, last version in central repo is 4.4. I can manualy download proguard 4.6+ from proguard repo, but how i can include it to plugin?

---

I have my own nexus repo, and i put proguard 4.8 there. How can i load dependecies for "proguard-maven-plugin" from my repo?

i did as written there: http://www.sonatype.com/people/2008/04/how-to-override-a-plugins-dependency-in-maven/, but maven looking proguard 4.8 in central repo. How can i force maven search in my own repo?

Sorry my terrible English, i hope you understand me.

Comment: how do you get normal dependencies from your internal nexus repo?

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the file `.m2/settings.xml` in your home folder (and the home folder of every user who runs the Maven job). There you have to add your Nexus as a repository as described [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html). Basically the config looks like this:

```
<settings>
  ...
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>mynexus</id>
      <name>My Nexus</name>
      <url>http://mynexusurl</url>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  ...
</settings>
```

Additionally you have to configure your Nexus to mirror the central repo.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will also help, I don't use it, but this is the form of the config for changing a dependency

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
            <artifactId>proguard</artifactId>
            <version>4.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Also an ant-run example

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ant-contrib</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant-contrib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0b2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ant</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant-nodeps</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

**Note also! for maven2** - *issues resolved maven3 http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-1323

For multi module reactor builds dependencies for plugin resolved in first use of the plugin.  If your dependency isn't being downloaded in reactor build but works fine in single module then you may need to include it in an earlier project - easiest done by adding to pluginManagement of shared parent*